# Wysiwyg custom control issue in IE8

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg

I am trying to find a solution for this issue in WYSIWYG editor.

I have a custom control in jQuery wysiwyg text editor. The control is a select dropdown and I want to insertHtml on selecting any option from the dropdown.
The problem is, in IE8, the Html is always inserted at the beginning irrespective of the cursor position.

Comment: What is the plugin / editor?

Comment: its a jquery wysiwyg text editor

Comment: Yes, you said that in your question, but I'm trying to find out which it is. Otherwise there is no way of helping you.

Comment: Ok, Its a jwysiwyg editor : https://github.com/akzhan/jwysiwyg/blob/master/README.rst